# Laravel Error "Unable to load the "app" configuration file" after Windows file restore

Tags: laravel

Bad mistake this morning. I uninstalled WAMP Server which deleted the Wamp folder and all its projects.

I restored the wamp folder from backup. WAMP is up and running on upgraded PHP and settings as before, however:

Laravel projects won't start - getting blank whoops pages on any Laravel project. When I cd into any project folder and try to run `php artisan`, I get:

```
Unable to load the "app" configuration file.
```

The `'config/app.php'` does indeed exist. And, all the restored files appear correct.

As a test, I installed a new Laravel project and it works correctly.  I also am able to clone a project from a Git repo, `npm update` & `composer install`, and that works. So, I don't think the problem is with the WAMP stack.

I need some direction troubleshooting this. Thanks!

Comment: Seems that you forgot to restore your .env file

Comment: try `php artisan -vvv` for a more verbose output

Comment: @omadonex all files are restored, including .env

Comment: @apokryfos adding `-vvv` still get only `[Exception]
  Unable to load the "app" configuration file.`

Comment: I'm not out of the woods yet, but did discover this:  Windows File History restored some file names in proper case, including `config\App.php` which should be `app.php`.  Fixing that, gets a new error that may well be related to improper filename case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that [Windows changes the case of *some* file names during restore](https://superuser.com/questions/1133296/windows-file-history-automatically-changes-some-filenames-to-uppercase).  What a drag.  There seems to be no reasonable answer except make the switch to Apple.

For example, in the Laravel config folder, Windows restored these files with proper case, `App.php, Auth.php, Queue.php, and View.php`.  Everything else was left lowercase as they need to be.

Correcting the case of these files fixed the problem for now (until I find other mis-cased files).

Answer (score -1):

Make sure this file exist

```
config/app.php
```